# Non matching attribute 'INSTANT COLUMN(s)' between partition and table

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a program that regularly exchanges a partition with a table.

`MyTable` is a partitioned table, and `MyTableTemplate` is an empty copy of this table, with the same structure but no partitioning.

The process is the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE MyTableTemplate;

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (...);
// more inserts...

ALTER TABLE MyTable EXCHANGE PARTITION p1 WITH TABLE tmp;
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

It worked fine so far, until I needed to add a column to the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MyTable         ADD COLUMN someColumn TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE MyTableTemplate ADD COLUMN someColumn TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Now when I run `EXCHANGE PARTITION WITH TABLE`, I get the following message:

> General error: 1731 Non matching attribute 'INSTANT COLUMN(s)' between partition and table

Oddly, if I do not add the column at the last position:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... AFTER someField;
```

...then the partition exchange works fine!

**What's this "`INSTANT COLUMN(s)` attribute" and what did I do wrong?**

Is this a bug? I'm using MySQL 8.0.12.

Comment: Specify `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` (or  `ALGORITHM=COPY` if in-place is not supported for your table's engine) in the `ALTER TABLE` statement explicitly.

Comment: @Akina Thanks a lot, this works perfectly! Is this expected behaviour? If you can move this to an answer, I'll accept it right away.

Comment: *If you can move this to an answer* To move the comment to the answer, it is necessary to tell more details. But I'm too lazy to study INSTANT COLUMN so deep, because do not need in this knowledge now. It helps? that's enough.

Comment: It sometimes just helps to have a solution, even if there's no full explanation. Other people might stumble upon this question with the same problem, and for this reason, it's always nice to have an accepted answer! I'll write a short one if you don't.

Comment: The exact cause is that your ALTER TABLE is "able" to profit of the "ALGORITHM=INSTANT" from MySQL 8, that is incredibly faster than INPLACE or COPY. So MySQL did it. (if you go update MySQL to 8.29 or newer, you may have the same error if the column is not even at the last position). This was unexpected for mysql team first, but they say it's now mentioned in their documentation (I suppose very implicitely cause' I didn't find it...), see this for more information: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` (or `ALGORITHM=COPY` if in-place is not supported for your table's engine) in the `ALTER TABLE` statement explicitly.